# I'm trying to find the sum of the objects that are defined as numbers

Tags: java

I'm doing an exercise, in which I have to create the method `add`, however due to p and v being defined as objects, I'm having a hard time figuring out how I can define this method in the syntax I've been given in the exercise (I'm only allowed to change the methods).

I would like to add the two inputs 5 and 17 so that it returns 22. I've done a lot of research into other questions where I've seen them write it as `Positiv(p + v)` but this doesn't quite work.

```
public class Positiv {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Positiv p = new Positiv(5);
            Positiv v = new Positiv(17);
            p.add(v);
            System.out.println(p.get());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private int n;

    public Positiv(int n) {
        if (n < 0) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("exception"); 
        }      
        this.n = n;
        }

    public static Positiv add(Positiv v)
    {
        return new Positiv(n + v);
    }

    public int get() {
        return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: try this `return new Positiv(n + v.get());`

Comment: What do you mean you can only change the methods?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `add` method:

```
public static Positiv add(Positiv v)
{
    return new Positiv(n + v);
}
```

You return a whole new `Positiv` object. However (correct me if I'm wrong) it looks as if you just want to add the two `n` fields. You can do this by adding `this.get` to `v.get`:

```
public void add(Positiv v)
{
    this.n += v.get();
}
```

Which will return `22`

---

Tutorial for [`this`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){

        Numbers a = new Numbers(5);
        Numbers b = new Numbers(10);

        int num1 = a.getN();
        int num2 = b.getN();

        System.out.println(addTwoNumbers(num1, num2));

     }

     public static int addTwoNumbers(int a, int b) {
         return a + b;
     }
}

class Numbers {
    private int n;

    public Numbers(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public int getN() {
        return n;
    }
}
```